# Android getContext Method

Tags: android, android-context

I'm so interested in `getContext()` method and how it works. For example, I wrote `recycleView`

```
@Override 
public RecycleView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent ,int viewtype)
{
View view =LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);}
```

and I call it on my fragment class defined to `MainActivity`.
My question here how does `getContext()` method return `MainActivity`? How does `getContext()` is understood?

I look at that method into the Android Studio, but I didn't understand it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ultimate reference: [Context | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Long story short, the `View` class, and thus all of it's subclasses (like `ViewGroup`), have a defined function called `getContext()` which returns a `Context` object. This class is abstract and the implementation is provided by the Android system, which is why the actual functionality is not easy to understand. It allows you to access global information about an application's environment, such as themes, resources, etc. It is pretty magical, but that magical aspect can be costly if you aren't careful. It is very easy to leak a Context object, which can quickly eat up RAM on the device.

Comment: Wow, awesome explanation in your last sentence you said which can quickly eat up RAM on the device. This is bad?(i mean using context) What do you advise for it ?instead

Comment: Using Context is good (and necessary), but it is very easy to use incorrectly. For example, using `Context.getApplicationContext()` is generally safer than just using `getContext()`. If at all possible, avoid passing `Context` to another class unless you have to, this is an easy way to leak a `Context` object. For more reading: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html